# $E(X^+) < \infty$ if and only if $\int_{\alpha}^{\infty}(−\log F(u)) du < \infty$ for some $\alpha > 0.$ where $F$ is distribution function of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with distribution function $F$. Show that $E(X^+) < \infty$ if and only if $\int_{\alpha} ^{\infty}(−\log F(u)) du < \infty$ for some $\alpha > 0$.

Here $X^+ = X\mathbb{1}_{(X>0)}$

I could prove $\int_{\alpha} ^{\infty}(−\log F(u)) du < ∞$ for some $\alpha > 0 $ implies $E(X^+)<\infty$. Any hints on how to prove the other direction will be helpful.

Comment: $\alpha$ has nothing to do with $\int_0^\infty(-\log F(u))\,\mathrm{d}u$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\int_0 ^{\infty}(−logF(u)) du < ∞$ for some $\alpha > 0 $?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I made an error while typing and corrected it. The lower limit of the integration is $\alpha$

Comment: I have taken the liberty of correcting one more error. I hope it is OK with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Bbb{E}(X_+) = \int_{0}^{\infty} \Bbb{P}(X>t)dt= \int_{0}^{\infty} (1-F(t))dt \ge \int_a^{\infty} (1-F(t))dt \ge \int_a^{\infty} -c\log(F(t))dt$$
where $a$ is the number such that $F(a)>0.5$, $c$ is a constant such that $1-x \ge -c\ln(x)$ for all $x \in [0.5,1]$.
Note that such constant $c$ exists because $\lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \frac{1-x}{-\ln(x)} =1$ and $\frac{1-x}{-\ln(x)} >0$ for all $x \in [0.5,1)$